# Как правильно задавать timestamp при отправке запроса на сторонний API?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня возникли проблемы с пониманием работы даты и времени в PHP.  Над своим вопросом не могу уже разобраться второй день. Прошу помочь разобраться. Есть API, куда я передаю:

*методы Carbon/Laravel*

```
'json' => [
                'dir' => 'ASC',
                'filter' => [
                    'delivering_date_from' => now()->format('Y-m-d'),
                    'delivering_date_to' => now()->addDays(7),
                    'status' => 'awaiting_registration '
                ],
                'limit' => 10,
                'offset' => 0,
                'with' => [
                    'analytics_data' => true,
                    'financial_data' => true,
                    'translit' => true
                ]
            ]
```

*метод РНР*

```
'json' => [
                'dir' => 'ASC',
                'filter' => [
                    'delivering_date_from' => date('Y-m-d'),
                    'delivering_date_to' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime(7)),
                    'status' => 'awaiting_registration '
                ],
                'limit' => 10,
                'offset' => 0,
                'with' => [
                    'analytics_data' => true,
                    'financial_data' => true,
                    'translit' => true
                ]
            ]
```

При этих двух вариантах я получаю ответ *{"code":3, "message":"proto: (line 1:47): invalid google.protobuf.Timestamp value "2023-08-05"", "details":[]}*

Если я использую метод *date()*, то я должен указать в каком формате передать + timestamp, который передавать необязательно или всё таки надо?

Comment: Почему бы не посмотреть метод API который вы используете и узнать в документации конкретно какой формат должен быть??

Comment: вот тут: https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-cloud-container-v1/latest/Google-Protobuf-Timestamp   написано: *"The range is from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z"*   .... вот такой формат и нужно делать

Comment: Если передавать тот формат, что указан в документации __"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.mcsZ"__, то получаю ошибку **invalid google.protobuf.Timestamp value "2023-Aug-MonT02:08:05.082023-08-07T14:25:05+00:0005Z""**

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.mcsZ` - это значит в таком формате `2023-08-07T01:02:03.004Z`, а не так `2023-Aug-MonT0202:08:05...`

Comment: @U-Lo надо передавать **правильный формат**, а не придуманный))

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл примерно такую ссылку: https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-cloud-container-v1/latest/Google-Protobuf-Timestamp  в которой сказано:

> The range is from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z

Вот такой формат и нужно делать. Если писать на чистом *PHP*, то это может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
        "y-m-d H:i:s",
        "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
        new \DateTimeZone("UTC")
    )
    ->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
```

где вместо `2020-01-01 00:00:00`  можно подставить тот же `date('Y-m-d')` и нули, если уточнения не требуются (или `date('Y-m-d h:i:s')`)

Answer (score 0):

Дату нужно передать в таком формате

```
...
'delivering_date_from' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'); // 2023-08-05T00:00:00Z
'delivering_date_to'   => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+7 days')); // 2023-08-12T00:00:00Z
...
```